# Call to undefined method stdClass::isOnline() in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, pusher

I'm trying to cheek the user is online or offline in my chat blade. I make a realtime chat in Laravel using Pusher and it's working fine but I have a issue to show user online offline status. I make middleware **LastUserActivity** and also registerd a my middleware in kernel.php but I constantly get this error.

**Call to undefined method stdClass::save()**

**middleware**

```
<?PHP

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use Cache;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class LastUserActivity
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    if(Auth::check()){
        $expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(1);
        Cache::put('user-is-online-'.Auth::user()->id, true, $expiresAt);
    }
    return $next($request);
  }
}
```

**User Model**

```
<?PHP

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Cache;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
   use Notifiable;

   /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
    protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'gender', 'dob', 'image', 'password', 'is_admin', 'mobile', 'service_id', 'country_id', 'city_id', 'piincode'
];

    /**
    * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

  /**
  * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
  *
  * @var array
  */
  protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
  ];

  //check if User is online
  public function isOnline()
  {
    return Cache::has('user-is-online-'. $this->id);
  }

}
```

**my blade file is**

```
<ul class="users">
    @foreach($users as $user)
       <li class="user" id="{{ $user->id }}">
           {{--will show unread count notification--}}
           @if($user->unread)
              <span class="pending">{{ $user->unread }}</span>
           @endif
           <div class="media">
              <div class="media-left">
                <img src="{{ URL::asset('storage/uploads/vendor/'.$user->image) }}" alt="" class="media-object">
             </div>
             <div class="media-body">
                <p class="name">{{ $user->name }}</p>
                <p class="email">{{ $user->email }}</p>
                 @if ($user->isOnline())
                     <li class="text-success">Online</li>
                 @else
                     <li class="text-muted">Offline</li>
                 @endif
             </div>
         </div>
      </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

**my controller file is**

```
<?PHP

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use App\Message;
 use App\User;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 use Pusher\Pusher;

 class ChatsController extends Controller
{

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('auth');
  }

  /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
 public function index()
 {

    $users = DB::select("select users.id, users.name, users.image, users.email, count(is_read) as unread 
    from users LEFT  JOIN  messages ON users.id = messages.from and is_read = 0 and messages.to = " . Auth::id() . "
    where users.id != " . Auth::id() . " 
    group by users.id, users.name, users.image, users.email");

    return view('admin.chat', ['users' => $users]);
 }
}
```

[image: error message]

please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: you cannot use `$user->isOnline()` on `DB::` you need to use model `User::all()`

Comment: @KamleshPaul sir thanks for your reply but how i join my messages table now??????

Comment: use Laravel relationship  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1):

```
 $users = DB::select("select users.id, users.name, users. ....
```

the $users will not hold a collection of user but a collection of std class ...

to hold a collection of users you should get the result using User Model ...

something like:

```
$users = User::selectRaw("users.id, users.name, users.image, users.email, count(is_read) as unread"
        )->leftJoin('messages', 'users.id', 'messages.from')
            ->where('is_read', 0)->where('messages.to', Auth::id())
            ->where('users.id', '!=', Auth::id())
            ->groupBy(['users.id', 'users.name', 'users.image', 'users.email'])->get();
```